# Radio options appearing all in one line

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectradio

I am re-using a global method to get all the picklist values for my select lists and radio lists:

**Controller**:

```
public List<SelectOption> getFrequencyOptions(){

    List<SelectOption> opts=getPicklistValues(sObjectRFC, 'Frequency__c');
    options.add(new SelectOption('',''));
    String[] options = new String[]{};

    for(SelectOption so : opts)
    {   
        system.debug(so.getValue());
    options.add(so.getValue());
    }        
    return options;
}

public list<SelectOption> getPicklistValues(SObject obj, String fld)
{
    list<SelectOption> options = new list<SelectOption>();
    // Get the object type of the SObject.
    Schema.sObjectType objType = obj.getSObjectType(); 
    // Describe the SObject using its object type.
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objDescribe = objType.getDescribe();       
    // Get a map of fields for the SObject
    map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objDescribe.fields.getMap(); 
    // Get the list of picklist values for this field.
    list<Schema.PicklistEntry> values = fieldMap.get(fld).getDescribe().getPickListValues();
    // Add these values to the selectoption list.
    options.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
    for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : values)
    { 
         options.add(new SelectOption(a.getLabel(), a.getValue())); 
    }
    return options;
}
```

**VF Page**:

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!sObjectRFC.Frequency__c}" id="outMailshot_Frequency__c">
    <apex:selectOptions  value="{!FrequencyOptions}"/>                                                    
</apex:selectRadio>
```

the problem is, in the page the list of options is coming out all in one line instead of nicely on several lines as in the left one below which is built the *classic* way:

[image]

Is there something else I need to do in order to have them format as the ones on the left?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `layout` option on [apex:selectRadio](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectRadio.htm). This will determine the appearance of the elements:

- lineDirection: the values go across the screen (DEFAULT VALUE).
- pageDirection: the values go down the screen.